# Como impido que se muestre el mismo Frame en tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite3

hola estoy creando mi app en tkinter python3 soy novato, y estoy teniendo problemas para Mostrar los datos sobre todo con los frame, cada vez que presiono el boton delivery se me carga toda la intefaz una de bajo de la otra quisiera que eso no pase. lo que busco es que no importa la veces que lede a un boton y que se muestre una vez. aqui mi codigo:

```
    from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import messagebox
import datetime


ventanaPrincipal = Tk()
ventanaPrincipal.config(bg='white')
ventanaPrincipal.geometry('1000x800')
ventanaPrincipal.title('Prueba')
ventanaPrincipal.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
ventanaPrincipal.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


#----------------------------------------------no tocar

def deliveryFuncion():

    def guardar_datos():
        nombre = nombre_entry.get()
        direccion = direccion_entry.get("1.0", END)
        telefono = telefono_entry.get()

        # Conectarse a la base de datos (o crearla si no existe)
        conexion = sqlite3.connect("datos.db")
        cursor = conexion.cursor()

        # Crear la tabla si todavia no existe
        cursor.execute('''
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contactos (
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                nombre TEXT NOT NULL,
                direccion TEXT NOT NULL,
                telefono INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE
            )
        ''')

        # Guardar los datos en la base de datos
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO contactos (nombre, direccion, telefono) VALUES (?,?,?)", (nombre, direccion, telefono))
        conexion.commit()

        # Cerrar la conexión con la base de datos
        conexion.close()

        messagebox.showinfo('Información', 'La dirección ha sido guarda correctamente.')
    def buscar_datos():
        telefono = telefono_entry.get()
        # Conectarse a la base de datos
        conexion = sqlite3.connect("datos.db")
        cursor = conexion.cursor()

        # Buscar los datos en la base de datos
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM contactos WHERE telefono=?", (telefono,))
        resultado = cursor.fetchone()

        # Mostrar los datos encontrados
        if resultado:
            nombre_mostrado.config(text=resultado[1])
            direccion_mostrada.config(text=resultado[2], fg="green")
            telefono_mostrado.config(text=resultado[3])
        else:
            nombre_mostrado.config(text="No se encontraron datos", fg="red")
            direccion_mostrada.config(text="")
            telefono_mostrado.config(text="")

        # Cerrar la conexión con la base de datos
        conexion.close()
    def editar_direccion():
        nueva_direccion = simpledialog.askstring("Editar Dirección", "Ingrese la nueva dirección:", parent=ventanaDelivery)
        if nueva_direccion:
            # Conectarse a la base de datos
            conexion = sqlite3.connect("datos.db")
            cursor = conexion.cursor()

            # Actualizar la dirección en la base de datos
            cursor.execute("UPDATE contactos SET direccion=? WHERE telefono=?", (nueva_direccion, telefono_mostrado['text']))
            conexion.commit()

            # Actualizar la dirección mostrada en la ventanaDelivery
            direccion_mostrada.config(text=nueva_direccion)

            # Cerrar la conexión con la base de datos
            conexion.close()
            
            messagebox.showinfo('Información', 'La dirección ha sido actualizada correctamente.')
    #-------interfaz delivery-------------
    ventanaDelivery= Frame(ventanaPrincipal, bg='white',)
    ventanaDelivery.pack()
    nombre_label = Label(ventanaDelivery, text="Nombre:", bg='white')
    nombre_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

    nombre_entry = Entry(ventanaDelivery, width=30, bg='white')
    nombre_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

    direccion_label = Label(ventanaDelivery, text="Dirección:", bg='white')
    direccion_label.grid(row=1, column=0)

    direccion_entry = Text(ventanaDelivery, width=30, height=4, bg='white')
    direccion_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

    telefono_label = Label(ventanaDelivery, text="Teléfono:", bg='white')
    telefono_label.grid(row=2, column=0)

    telefono_entry = Entry(ventanaDelivery, width=30, bg='white')
    telefono_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)

    guardar_boton = Button(ventanaDelivery, text="Guardar", command=guardar_datos, bg="green", fg="white")
    guardar_boton.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=10, sticky=E)

    buscar_boton = Button(ventanaDelivery, text="Buscar", command=buscar_datos, bg="blue", fg="white")
    buscar_boton.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, padx=10)
    
    # Sección para mostrar datos
    nombre_mostrado_label = Label(ventanaDelivery, text="Nombre:", bg='white')
    nombre_mostrado_label.grid(row=4, column=0)

    nombre_mostrado = Label(ventanaDelivery, text="", bg='white')
    nombre_mostrado.grid(row=4, column=1)

    direccion_mostrada_label = Label(ventanaDelivery, text="Dirección:", bg='white')
    direccion_mostrada_label.grid(row=5, column=0)

    direccion_mostrada = Label(ventanaDelivery, text="", bg='white')
    direccion_mostrada.grid(row=5, column=1)

    telefono_mostrado_label = Label(ventanaDelivery, text="Teléfono:", bg='white')
    telefono_mostrado_label.grid(row=6, column=0)

    telefono_mostrado = Label(ventanaDelivery, text="", bg='white')
    telefono_mostrado.grid(row=6, column=1)


    editar_direccion_boton = Button(ventanaDelivery, text="Editar Dirección", command=editar_direccion, bg="red", fg="white")
    editar_direccion_boton.grid(row=7, column=1, padx=10)
    


    
def cuadreFuncion():
    ventanaCuadre= Frame(ventanaPrincipal, bg='white')
    ventanaCuadre.pack()
    
    
    # Variables para almacenar los valores de entrada
    facturas = IntVar()
    venta = IntVar()
    gasto = IntVar()
    total = IntVar()
    
    # Función para calcular y mostrar el total
    def calcular_total():
        total.set(facturas.get() + venta.get() + gasto.get())

    # Función para guardar el total en un archivo de texto
    def guardar_total():
        calcular_total()
        fecha_hora = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")
        nombre_archivo = "cuadres/cuadre" + fecha_hora + ".txt"
        
        with open(nombre_archivo, "w") as f:
            f.write(str(f'\tFacturas: {facturas.get()}\n\tEfectivo: {venta.get()}\n\tGasto de la empresa: {gasto.get()}\n\tTotal Vendido: {total.get()}\n\tComentario: \n\t {texto_comentario.get("1.0", "end")} \n\tFirma: \n\t {texto_nombre.get("1.0", "end")}'))

        messagebox.showinfo('Información', 'Su cuadre ya ha sido guardada ahora se generara una impresion de este.')
    
    # Etiquetas
    etiqueta_facturas = Label(ventanaCuadre, text="Facturas", bg='white')
    etiqueta_facturas.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

    etiqueta_venta = Label(ventanaCuadre, text="Efectivo", bg='white')
    etiqueta_venta.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

    etiqueta_gasto = Label(ventanaCuadre, text="Gasto", bg='white')
    etiqueta_gasto.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

    etiqueta_total = Label(ventanaCuadre, text="Total vendido", bg='white')
    etiqueta_total.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

    etiqueta_comentario = Label(ventanaCuadre, text="Comentarios: ", bg='white')
    etiqueta_comentario.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

    etiqueta_nombre = Label(ventanaCuadre, text="Firma: ", bg='white')
    etiqueta_nombre.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

    # Entradas de texto
    texto_facturas = Entry(ventanaCuadre, textvariable=facturas, bg='white')
    texto_facturas.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

    texto_venta = Entry(ventanaCuadre, textvariable=venta, bg='white')
    texto_venta.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

    texto_gasto = Entry(ventanaCuadre, textvariable=gasto, bg='white')
    texto_gasto.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

    texto_total = Entry(ventanaCuadre, textvariable=total, state="readonly", bg='white')
    texto_total.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

    texto_comentario = Text(ventanaCuadre, width=20, height=5, bg='white')
    texto_comentario.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

    texto_nombre = Text(ventanaCuadre, width=20, height=1, bg='white')
    texto_nombre.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

    # Botones
    boton_calcular = Button(ventanaCuadre, text="Calcular", bg="green", fg='white', font=('Dosis', 12, 'bold'), command=calcular_total)
    boton_calcular.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

    boton_guardar = Button(ventanaCuadre, text="Guardar e Imprimir", bg="red", fg='white', font=('Dosis', 12, 'bold'), command=guardar_total)
    boton_guardar.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

    boton_salir = Button(ventanaCuadre, text="Salir del programa", bg="blue", fg='white', font=('Dosis', 12, 'bold'), command=ventanaCuadre.destroy)
    boton_salir.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, columnspan=2)
   

def funcionMenu():
    def cierreMenu():
        barraMenu.destroy()
        botonMenu.config(text='☰')
        botonMenu.config(command=funcionMenu)
        
    barraMenu = Frame(ventanaPrincipal, bg='#158aff')
 #---------Boton ventas ---------------  
    
    #carritoPng = PhotoImage(file="img/carro.png", format='png', width=24, height=24)
    ventasBoton = Button(barraMenu, text='Ventas', bg='#158aff', font=('Bold', 20), bd=0, fg='white',
                         activebackground='#158aff', activeforeground='white', highlightthickness=0)
    ventasBoton.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
    #carritoLabel = Label(barraMenu, image=carritoPng)
    #carritoLabel.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
    
    
 #----------boton delivery-------------
 
    deliveryBoton = Button(barraMenu, text='Delivery', bg='#158aff', font=('Bold', 20), bd=0, fg='white',
                         activebackground='#158aff', activeforeground='white', highlightthickness=0, command=deliveryFuncion)
    deliveryBoton.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
 #----------boton Cuadre-------------
 
    cuadreBoton = Button(barraMenu, text='Cuadres', bg='#158aff', font=('Bold', 20), bd=0, fg='white',
                         activebackground='#158aff', activeforeground='white', highlightthickness=0, command=cuadreFuncion)
    cuadreBoton.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
 #----------boton Calculadora-------------
 
    calculadoraBoton = Button(barraMenu, text='Calculadora', bg='#158aff', font=('Bold', 20), bd=0, fg='white',
                         activebackground='#158aff', activeforeground='white', highlightthickness=0)
    calculadoraBoton.grid(row=3, column=0,sticky=W)
 #----------boton Admin-------------
 
    adminBoton = Button(barraMenu, text='Administración', bg='#158aff', font=('Bold', 20), bd=0, fg='white',
                         activebackground='#158aff', activeforeground='white', highlightthickness=0)
    adminBoton.grid(row=4, column=0,sticky=W)
    
    #----------boton Ayuda-------------
    ayudaBoton = Button(barraMenu, text='Ayuda', bg='#158aff', font=('Bold', 20), bd=0, fg='white',
                         activebackground='#158aff', activeforeground='white', highlightthickness=0)
    ayudaBoton.grid(row=5, column=0,sticky=W)
 #----------boton aserca de-------------
    acercaBoton = Button(barraMenu, text='Acerca de...', bg='#158aff', font=('Bold', 20), bd=0, fg='white',
                         activebackground='#158aff', activeforeground='white', highlightthickness=0)
    acercaBoton.grid(row=6, column=0,sticky=W)
 #----------boton salir-------------
 
    salirBoton = Button(barraMenu, text='Salir', bg='#158aff', font=('Bold', 20), bd=0, fg='white', command=quit,
                         activebackground='#158aff', activeforeground='white', highlightthickness=0)
    salirBoton.grid(row=7, column=0,sticky=W)

    
    ventanaAltura = ventanaPrincipal.winfo_height()

    barraMenu.place(x=0, y=50, height=ventanaAltura, width=250)
    botonMenu.config(text='X')
    botonMenu.config(command=cierreMenu)

menuFrame = Frame(ventanaPrincipal, bg='#158aff') # , heighlightbackground='white', heighlightthickness=1
menuFrame.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
menuFrame.pack_propagate(False)
menuFrame.configure(height=50)

botonMenu = Button(menuFrame, text='☰', bg='#158aff', fg='white', command=funcionMenu,
                  font=('Bold', 20), bd=0,  activebackground='#158aff', activeforeground='white')

botonMenu.pack(side=LEFT)

tituloMenu = Label(menuFrame, text='Menu De opciones', font=('Bold', 20), bg='#158aff', fg='white')
tituloMenu.pack(side=LEFT)


ventanaPrincipal.mainloop()
```

[image: Este es el menu antes de darle]

[image: este es despues]

Me dirijo a ustedes en busca de ayuda con un problema que tengo en Tkinter en Python. Estoy trabajando en una aplicación que utiliza Tkinter para crear una interfaz gráfica de usuario y me encuentro con un problema que no logro solucionar.

El problema es el siguiente: tengo un botón que, cuando se presiona, carga un Frame debajo de la otra. Lo que quiero es que, no importa cuántas veces se presione el botón, solo se muestre una Frame en todo momento.

como les contaba Mi aplicación tiene un botón "delivery" que, cuando se presiona, carga un Frame debajo del otro. Sin embargo, quiero evitar que el Frame se muestre más de una vez, independientemente de cuántas veces se presione el botón. He investigado sobre toplevel, pero eso abre una nueva ventana independiente de la principal, y lo que quiero es que los datos se actualicen en el mismo Frame.

¿Alguno de ustedes ha enfrentado un problema similar o sabe cómo solucionarlo? Estoy seguro de que su ayuda será muy valiosa para mí y agradeceré cualquier consejo o solución que puedan brindarme. Gracias por su tiempo y espero su respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Centrémonos en una de las opciones del menú, por ejemplo "Delivery".

Una forma simple podría ser almacenar en alguna variable cuál es el estado de tu programa. Por ejemplo, si está activa la "pantalla" de Delivery. Entonces, la `functionDelivery()` comenzaría mirando esa variable. Si está activa no tiene que hacer nada, y retorna inmediatamente. Si no está activa, entonces crea la interfaz de usuario y cambia el valor de esa variable para señalar que está activa.

¿Cuándo debería desactivarse de nuevo? En mi opinión debería hacerlo cuando el usuario pulse en "Guardar datos", pero en realidad sólo tú sabes realmente cuál es el comportamiento deseado de tu aplicación. Tal como yo lo veo, cuando el usuario pulse "Guardar datos" habría que destruir la "pantalla" que tenía el formulario para capturar los datos, y volver a cambiar la variable que guarda el estado, para indicar que "delivery" ya no está activo. Esto se haría por tanto desde la función `guardar_datos()` (interna a `deliveryFunction()`)

Ya que tu implementación se basa en funciones, el estado debe guardarse fuera de la función, pero accesible desde ella. Es decir, en una variable global. Así pues, estos son los cambios que yo haría en tu código, con respecto a la parte de Delivery:

```
#----------------------------------------------no tocar
deliveryActive = False
def deliveryFuncion():
    global deliveryActive
    if deliveryActive:
        return
    deliveryActive = True

    def guardar_datos():
        global deliveryActive
        # El resto de esta función tal y como la tenías
        # salvo que al final añado esto
        # destruir interfaz
        ventanaDelivery.destroy()
        deliveryActive = False
```

Puedes comprobar que con este cambio, aunque pulses varias veces el botón Delivery, no se crean más formularios en la ventana. Cuando le das a "Guardar", el formulario desaparece, y el botón permitirá otra vez crear otro.

Parecería que basta replicar este esquema para cada opción de menú, y efectivamente esto funcionará en parte, pero la cosa se complica si permites que el usuario pueda pulsar otra opción de menú mientras tenía una activa.

Por ejemplo, imagina que ha pulsado "Delivery" y ha aparecido el formulario correspondiente. ¿Qué ha de ocurrir si ahora pulsa el botón "Cuadres"? Bajo mi punto de vista creo que eso debería ser equivalente a salir de "Delivery" y entrar en "Cuadres", por tanto se debería destruir el formulario que estaba visible, y poner a `False` la variable `deliveryActive` antes de entrar a la función `cuadreFuncion()`.

Por desgracia no es posible hacer esas cosas con tu estructura de código actual, pues para destruir el formulario de Delivery es necesario acceder a la variable `ventanaDelivery` y esa sólo es accesible desde dentro de la función `deliveryFuncion()` y no desde `cuadreFuncion()` que es donde la necesitaríamos en este caso.

Podrías hacer globales esas variables, pero el código empieza a volverse farragoso y lleno de variables globales, lo que no es deseable.

Creo que mejor sería **impedir** que el usuario pueda usar ninguna opción del menú mientras no haya terminado con la opción "actual". Es decir, cada "pantalla" debería ofrecer un botón "Terminar" además del de "Guardar", para poder volver a la pantalla principal. Mientras no se esté en la pantalla principal, el menú no debería permitir abrirse.

Podrías entonces tener una variable global que indique en qué estado te hallas (por ejemplo, podría tener los valores "Principal", "Delivery", "Cuadre", etc.. y según el valor de esa variable tomar las acciones necesarias desde cada función asociada al menú.

A la larga te recomendaría refactorizar tu código (es decir, volver a escribirlo de otra forma, pero preservando su funcionalidad) para hacerlo más orientado a objetos (clases).

Comment: si funciono pero cuando pulso otros botones se siguen poniendo 1 debajo del otro, por ejemplo si pulso cuadre y vuelvo y pulso cuadre no pasa na y genial hasta ahi porque cuando pulso delivery se carga debajo de cuadre, lo mismo pasa si pulso delivery y despues cuadre porque cree un funcion global para cuadres tambien. alguna solucion?

Comment: Como te comenté, tienes que repensarte el diseño del sistema. Deberías hacer, por ejemplo, que el menú desaparezca al elegir una de sus opciones, y sea reemplazado por la pantalla con el formulario que corresponda a esa opción. Al terminar de rellenar ese formulario (que debería tener un botón "salir") deberías destruir la pantalla del formulario y volver a crear la del menú

Comment: Aquí tienes una posible reimplementación que he estado haciendo como pasatiempo: https://gist.github.com/abul4fia/9783b2c7939e0c79ba0bb50c63e049ce  La interfaz de usuario es un poco torpe y no me gusta, pero era por aprovechar el código que ya tenías. Al elegir una opción del menú, éste desaparece (así el usuario no puede volver a elegirla, ni esa ni otra) y la "hamburguesa" para hacer reaparecer el menú se cambia por "..." y tampoco deja desplegar menú. Hasta que se sale del formulario. Entonces la hamburguesa reaparece y se puede elegir otra opción del menú

Comment: Cada "pantalla" de la aplicación se implementa creando una clase que herede de `Componente`. He implementado así dos de ellas: la del caso "Delivery" y la del caso "Cuadre". Tendrías que seguir un esquema similar para las demás. He estructurado el código en clases, evitando así todas esas variables globales. Las funciones de la misma clase comparten ciertas variables a través de `self`